# Resizing windows without constraints in IB Xcode 4.4

Tags: macos, interface-builder, xcode4.4

When laying out an `NSPanel` in IB I usually open a big window space, add and lay out the content elements, then resize the window to fit.

In Xcode 4.4 the items I add always seem to have space constraints associated with them and resize as I resize the enclosing elements and I can't seem to be able to turn this behaviour off.

I've tried setting the constraints to 'less than or equal', but it has no effect. This is insanely irritating, it's as if I need to build my UI from the outside inward, which is crazy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable the auto layout check-box in attributes for the xib...

I had the same problem but found this on google:  http://gentlebytes.com/2011/09/auto-layout-in-lion/